# How do I use Visual Studio 2010 config transforms for the applicationSettings section of the web.config?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config, slowcheetah

I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2010, and I am playing around with the Config transforms option for web application projects. I see in the example file how to change the connection strings, but I want to change settings in the applicationSettings (Not appsettings) section.  I have not been able to find any information on this.

I tried the following which worked, but I thought there might be a better way:

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <MyDashboard.Web.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="SomePath" serializeAs="String" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
        <value>c:\somewhere test</value>
      </setting>
    </MyDashboard.Web.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It will replace all the applicationSettings node.

```
<applicationSettings xdt:Transform="Replace"> 
    <MyDashboard.Web.Properties.Settings> 
      <setting name="SomePath" serializeAs="String"> 
        <value>c:\somewhere production</value> 
      </setting> 
    </MyDashboard.Web.Properties.Settings> 
  </applicationSettings>
```

Comment: I just wanted to mention that there is a known issue with this method which puts a line break after the new value, this caused problems for me, however the is a workaround posted here which worked flawlessly: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/544183/web-config-transform-writes-extra-line-break-spaces-to-values-elements-under-applicationsettings-section#

Answer (score 1):

Semi-related ... check out the SlowCheetah VS add-in at ... [visualstudiogallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)